# Frame initialization failed

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="Myvalue.apps.googleusercontent.com">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="my-signin2"></div>
  <script>
    function onSuccess(googleUser) {
      console.log('Logged in as: ' + googleUser.getBasicProfile().getName());
    }
    function onFailure(error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
    function renderButton() {
      gapi.signin2.render('my-signin2', {
        'scope': 'profile email',
        'width': 240,
        'height': 50,
        'longtitle': true,
        'theme': 'dark',
        'onsuccess': onSuccess,
        'onfailure': onFailure
      });
    }
  </script>

  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=renderButton" async defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tited to sign in using google but get these errors

cb=gapi.loaded_0?le=scs:177 Uncaught
{error: 'idpiframe_initialization_failed', details: 'You have created a new client application that use…i/web/guides/gis-migration) for more information.'}
details
:
"You have created a new client application that uses libraries for user authentication or authorization that will soon be deprecated. New clients must use the new libraries instead; existing clients must also migrate before these libraries are deprecated. See the [Migration Guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/gis-migration) for more information."
error
:
"idpiframe_initialization_failed"

Comment: The error is very clear to you that you are trying to create a client application that uses libraries for user authentication/authorization that will soon be deprecated, why can't you read the **migration guide**  on how to re-write your client application with the correct implementation instead.

Comment: doing this for the very first time didn't get a single clue about it

Answer (score 0):

Authentication and authorization with Google signin changed in **HTML** and **JavaScript**.

In this **authentication-only sign-in scenario**, example code and renderings of the existing Google Sign-In button are shown. Select from either Popup or Redirect mode to see differences in how the authentication response is handled either by a JavaScript callback or by secure redirect to your back-end server login endpoint.

**The old way** and deprecated.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
    <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="YOUR_CLIENT_ID">
    <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="handleCredentialResponse"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**The new way**

To use the new library in a simple **authentication-only sign-in** scenario select from either the **Popup** or **Redirect** mode and use the code sample to replace your existing implementation on your login page.

**So what is the popup way:**
Use a callback to handle sign-in directly from the user's browser.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
    <div id="g_id_onload"
         data-client_id="YOUR_CLIENT_ID"
         data-callback="handleCredentialResponse">
    </div>
    <div class="g_id_signin" data-type="standard"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**And the redirect way is:**
Google invokes your login endpoint as specified by the data-login_url attribute. Previously, you were responsible for the POST operation and parameter name. The new library posts the ID token to your endpoint in the credential parameter. Lastly, verify the ID token on your back-end server.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
    <div id="g_id_onload"
         data-client_id="YOUR_CLIENT_ID"
         data-ux_mode="redirect"
         data-login_uri="https://www.example.com/your_login_endpoint">
    </div>
    <div class="g_id_signin" data-type="standard"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Namwanza Ronald thank you so much added this new function in my code and after some changings it finally worked for me

Comment: Then, feel free to give me +1 and accept this answer. Thanks ! Happy coding !